# Pass value and redirect user from ASP.NET to PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, redirect, httpwebrequest

I have a scenario here whereby, on ASP.NET server side (domain A), some data (string data) needs to be pass over to PHP server side (domain B), and then the user will be redirected from Domain A to Domain B.

Can this be done over http? Or should it be on https?
Should the data be encrypted if on https?

I've read on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856894/passing-values-from-asp-net-to-php)

that it can be done using httpwebrequest.

should the data be pass via httpwebrequest then only response.redirect from .net to php ? Or can the httpwebrequest do the redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http and Https will depend on the data which you want to post to php. How much data is private like password or Credit Card Number etc. Similarly encryption.

Here is a question on SO about https

1. [Why not use HTTPS for everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746047/why-not-use-https-for-everything)
2. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38832/should-a-site-have-ssl-if-it-doesnt-have-a-login-form

If you want to transfer the control over another site then you should use `response.redirect`. You can not use `httpwebrequest` in this condition.

You can pass the values in the `querystring` or you can pass the values in the `body`.

### Edit 1

Pass values in body using Response.Redirect

[Response.Redirect with POST instead of Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get#answer-46700)

Comment: @mason here is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/response-redirect-with-post-instead-of-get#answer-46700)

Comment: Hi, thx for the reply. Now, I'm more interested when you mean pass the values in the body. could you show a simple example of pass values in the body?